# Weblogic: How do I list all logged on users?

Tags: weblogic, administration, weblogic9.x

I'd like to list the currently logged on users for my Weblogic domain

Failing that, I'd like to know how many users are logged on.

Ideally by using the admin console, or a script if I must.

Comment: There is a runtime group called "users" within weblogic which stores all authenticated users. But this is not visible from the console. If anyone knows how to view this, would help you.

Comment: Thanks - that would require  a script. I might need to go there

Comment: @Paul were you able to list the users using a script?

Comment: No, but I didn't try too hard, the requirement became less important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary of Deployments  > "deployment unit" > Monitoring > Sessions

Comment: Thanks :) 7.5 year later, I no longer need the answer but it's good to have one for other readers.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul This is the third longest accepted answer delay on the whole SO.

Comment: @peterh, hey, I got there eventually (I think there was an upvote that drew my attention to it again)